# $\gcd(|G|, |\text{Aut}(G)|)=1$ means G is abelian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, sylow-theory

> Prove the following assuming that $G$ is finite group with $\gcd(|G|, |\text{Aut}(G)|)=1$.
>
> a) G is abelian (done).
>
> b) Every Sylow subgroup of $G$ is cyclic of prime order.

Since G is abelian than every Sylow subgroup is unique, but does it mean cyclic?

Any suggestion?

Comment: Hint: consider inner automorphisms $x\mapsto gxg^{-1}$. The condition tells you they are all trivial, so $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Yes, so the homomorphism from $G$ to ${\rm Aut}(G)$ mapping $g$ to the automorphism $c_g$ defined by conjugation by $g$ must be trivial. So $c_g$ is the trivial homomorphism for all $g \in G$.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat you are right thank you.

Comment: For the second assertion it suffices to notice $|Aut(\mathbb Z/(p) \oplus \mathbb Z/(p))|=(p^2-1)(p^2-p)$ and (for $n \geq 2$) $|Aut(\mathbb Z/(p^n))|=p^n-p^{n-1}$ are divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, the inner automorphism group $\text{Inn}(G)$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$ so $\lvert\text{Inn}(G)\rvert$ divides $\lvert\text{Aut}(G)\rvert$.
However, $\text{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$ so $\lvert\text{Inn}(G)\rvert$ divides $\lvert G\rvert$. In our case where $\gcd(\lvert\text{Aut}(G)\rvert,\lvert G\rvert)=1$, this forces $\text{Inn}(G)=1$. Since $\text{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$, we must have $G=Z(G)$, meaning that $G$ is abelian.

For the second part, we will use the classification of finite abelian groups which states that
$$G\cong C_{p_1^{a_1}}\times C_{p_2^{a_2}}\times\cdots\times C_{p_k^{a_k}}$$
for (not necessarily distinct) primes $p_j$. If some $a_j\geq2$ then
$$\lvert\text{Aut}(C_{p_j^{a_j}})\rvert=\varphi(p_j^{a_j})=p_j^{a_j-1}(p_j-1)$$
is divisible by $p_j$. However, $\text{Aut}(C_{p_j^{a_j}})$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$ so $\lvert\text{Aut}(G)\rvert$ is divisible by $p_j$ which is a contradiction.
Thus, each $a_j=1$. If $p_i=p_j$ for some $i\neq j$ then
$$\lvert\text{Aut}(C_{p_i}\times C_{p_j})\rvert=(p_j^2-1)(p_j^2-p_j)$$
is divisible by $p_i$. However, $\text{Aut}(C_{p_i}\times C_{p_j})$ is a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(G)$ so $\lvert\text{Aut}(G)\rvert$ is divisible by $p_j$ which is a contradiction. Thus, $p_i\neq p_j$ for all $i\neq j$.

---

Moreover, it is easy to see that $p_i\nmid p_j-1$ for all $i,j$, which shows that every group of order $\lvert G\rvert$ is cyclic!

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_cyclicity-forcing_numbers

Comment: For your last part: Moreover, it is easy to see that pi not divisible pj-1 for all i, j, which shows that every group of order |G| is cyclic. Could you elaborate more plz since I don't know how to get that. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew If $G\cong C_{p_1}\times\cdots\times C_{p_k}$, then $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\cong C_{p_k-1}\times\cdots\times C_{p_k-1}$. In particular, $\lvert G\rvert=p_1\cdots p_k$ and $\lvert\mathrm{Aut}(G)\rvert=(p_1-1)\cdots(p_k-1)$. Since we are assuming that $\gcd(\lvert G\rvert,\lvert\mathrm{Aut}(G)\rvert)=1$, we can conclude that $p_i\nmid p_j-1$.

Comment: But why follows that G is cyclic?

Comment: See this link: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_cyclicity-forcing_numbers