# A proposed problems from American Math Monthly from Vol 119 NO.10 Dec 2012

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let ${\rm Aut}\, G$ denotes the automorphism group of $G$. Prove that there is no finite group with $|{\rm Aut}\,G|=|G|+1$.

I begin by suppose there is a finite group with the above property.

First of all $G$ cannot be non-abelian, For if does then as ${\rm Inn}\,G\cong G$ so we have $\gcd(|{\rm Aut}\,G|,|G|)>1$. And this is false as $\gcd(|G|+1,|G|)=1$.

So $G$ must be abelian.

From now on I have no progress. Any hint? I think maybe decompose $G$ into a finite direct product of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ could help to derive some contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $|G|$ and $|{\rm Aut}(G)|$ are coprime, we not only know that $G$ is abelian, but also that - see here:

[$\gcd(|G|, |\text{Aut}(G)|)=1$ means G is abelian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131793/gcdg-textautg-1-means-g-is-abelian)

So $G$ is cyclic of square-free order - see here:

[$|G|$ and $|{\rm Aut}(G)|$ are relatively prime $\Rightarrow$ $G$ should be cyclic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437334/g-and-rm-autg-are-relatively-prime-rightarrow-g-should-be-cycl?rq=1)

But for cyclic groups $G$ the claim is clear. If $|G|=n$, then ${\rm Aut}(G)|=\phi(n)$.